# How to properly use CharacterController.Move() to move the character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I created a basic First Person Controller but my problem is when i move both forward and sideways i move faster.

How can i add `moveDirectionForward` and `moveDirectionSide` in 1 Vector3 to be able to use `CharacterController.Move()` instead of  `CharacterController.SimpleMove()`?

```
void MovePlayer() {

    // Get Horizontal and Vertical Input
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    // Calculate the Direction to Move based on the tranform of the Player
    Vector3 moveDirectionForward = transform.forward * verticalInput * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 moveDirectionSide = transform.right * horizontalInput * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Apply Movement to Player
    myCharacterController.SimpleMove (moveDirectionForward + moveDirectionSide);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use a normalized vector for the direction of the movement.

```
// Get Horizontal and Vertical Input
float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

// Calculate the Direction to Move based on the tranform of the Player
Vector3 moveDirectionForward = transform.forward * verticalInput;
Vector3 moveDirectionSide = transform.right * horizontalInput;

//find the direction
Vector3 direction = (moveDirectionForward + moveDirectionSide).normalized;
//find the distance
Vector3 distance = direction * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

// Apply Movement to Player
myCharacterController.Move (distance);
```

---

### Performance note:

> `vector.normalized` is obtained from `vector/vector.magnitude`  and
>   `vector.magnitude` is obtained from `sqrt(vector.sqrMagnitude)` which
>   is heavy to process. To reduce the processing weight you can use
>   `vector/vector.sqrMagnitude` instead of `vector.normalized` but be
>   ware the result is not exactly the same, but still is in the same
>   direction.

---

> now i just need to apply gravity

Subtract `moveDirection.y` by the gravity multiplied by `Time.deltaTime`.
You can also simplify and reduce the code in the `MovePlayer` function by using `Vector3` and `TransformDirection`.

```
public float walkSpeed = 10.0f;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
CharacterController myCharacterController = null;

void Start()
{
    myCharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void MovePlayer()
{
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection *= walkSpeed;

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    myCharacterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the `CharacterController.Move` part. Op wants to use that instead of `SimpleMove`.

Comment: I can use .Move now i just need to apply gravity. Thanks for help!

Comment: by reducing the code i get the same problem i move faster

Comment: I think you have to normalize the direction like Bijan did `transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection.normalized);` instead of `transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection)`. If that doesn't work, undo what you just did and just replace `moveDirection *= walkSpeed;` with `moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * walkSpeed;`.

Comment: Yeah adding .normalized to the reduced code version works. Thanks everyone for the help. I got some studying to do now, i learned a lot from this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the normalized vector of the two axes when you multiply by your `walkSpeed`. The reason being is this will ensure that you always move in any direction with the same magnitude (1) no matter the angle. Whereas your current setup has non-orthogonal movement being being calculated at >1 magnitude. So something like this should work in your situation.

```
void MovePlayer()
{

    // Get Horizontal and Vertical Input
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // Calculate the Direction to Move based on the tranform of the Player
    Vector3 moveDirectionForward = transform.forward * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 moveDirectionSide = transform.right * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime;

    // Apply Movement to Player
    myCharacterController.SimpleMove((moveDirectionForward + moveDirectionSide).normalized * walkspeed);
```

Simply move the walkSpeed multiplication to the SimpleMove call against the normalized vector. The image below should help to visualize the problem you're having. By normalizing the vector before applying the walk speed, you're making sure that the direction vector is the same magnitude (effectively distance in this case) no matter what direction before you apply the walk speed.

[image]