# Unity CharacterController always moves in the same direction independent from rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If i'm rotating my player on the Y-Axis and move it like
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime)
it will move along the Z-Axis of the character (as expected).
If I used CharacterController.Move it will always move in the same direction, independent from its rotation.

How can I make the player follow it's rotation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly use CharacterController.Move() to move the character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493987/how-to-properly-use-charactercontroller-move-to-move-the-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are translating the character forward on a global level. This means forward will always be in the same direction. Instead, use `transform.forward`. That way, you are translating the player on the forward vector on the player.

Another way to do it is using `transform.rotation * Vector3.forward`. This will rotate the global forward by the rotation of the player, returning the same thing as `transform.forward`.